# Swapping positive and negative values in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of numbers in notepad++ that I need X value +- signs swapped. Trying to create a expression or script to make it happen. List like this:

```
<Polygon Type="Field">
      <Point X="-2" Y="424" />
      <Point X="698" Y="-278" />
      <Point X="477" Y="-499" />
      <Point X="1" Y="-4" />
      <Point X="-2664" Y="-2486" />
      <Point X="-2817" Y="-2322" />
```

Need to change X values only to be like this:

```
<Polygon Type="Field">
      <Point X="2" Y="424" />
      <Point X="-698" Y="-278" />
      <Point X="-477" Y="-499" />
      <Point X="-1" Y="-4" />
      <Point X="2664" Y="-2486" />
      <Point X="2817" Y="-2322" />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the browser? within notepad++? with a regex?

Comment: Within notepad++ and regex if possible. The format needs to stay the same, as I will be importing file after the change. Opening with Excel and making changes, changes the format of all the data entirely therefore invalidating the import. Any other way to make this change, I am open to as long as the format remains the same as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congrats on your first question. You can read more about this here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html

Find string is `X="(-)?(\d+)"`

Replace string is `X="(?1:-)\2"`

Key here is the replacement conditional which has the syntax `(?xyyy:zzz)`. If the capture group `x` is fulfilled, then it replaces with `yyy`, otherwise `zzz`. So, dash with nothing, and nothing with dash.

Comment: EXCELLENT!! Thanks a bunch!